# Fire an event on close of multiselect dropdown in Angular material

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, dom, angular-material

How to fire an event on close of multiselect dropdown in angular material?
This is my HTML template

```
                  <mat-select  multiple
                  (focusout)="triggerEvent($event)">
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of templateOptions"[value]="option">
                      {{option.name}}
                    </mat-option>
                  </mat-select>
                </mat-form-field>
```

As of now event is getting fired on every selection of options. I want it to be triggered when user has done selecting all the values and clicks outside. I have tried blur also but same result.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
<mat-select multiple (openedChange)="triggerEvent($event)">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of templateOptions"[value]="option">
        {{option.name}}
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Seems like you are looking for openedChange event emitter. Event emitted when the select panel has been toggled.

[document](https://material.angular.io/components/select/api)

Comment: With openedChange event triggers fine but $event will be true or false based on the state of select panel. How to get selected values now?

Comment: triggerEvent($event.value)

Comment: When we use openedChange(),  $event will be true or false. It will not have "value" property.

Comment: I am not familiar with Angular Material but you may try [(ngModel)] to bind the value instead.

Answer (score 13):

in version of angular material that i use(7.1.1>) you can use closed event like this:

```
 <mat-select (closed)="method()">
 ...
 </mat-select>
```

see this example in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-select-closed).